# PHP что дальше

Tags: php

Я уже закончил изучать PHP на базовом уровне (PHP+ООП). 
И начал задумываться, что изучать дальше, и как я понял, что дальше надо изучать frameworks...

Подскажите, что изучать дальше, и если это framework, то с какого начать.

Comment: Выбор не велик: коран || библия =)

Comment: @Виталий Кустов о, вы таки не представляете, сколь долго можно продолжать этот ряд)

Comment: тут задание есть, хорошее чтобы проверить свои навыки https://php.ru/forum/threads/kak-bystro-osvoit-php.52331/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я уже закончил изучать PHP на базовом
> уровне

Это все фигня! Базовый уровень это всё фигня.

Продолжай изучать PHP и потихонечку переходить на изучение архитектуры MVC.

А вообще лучше придумай себе проект и начни его реализацию, тогда точно будешь наступать на грабли, пить кофе, не спать днями, а потом научишься программировать и напишешь что ты закончил изучать PHP.

Comment: Закончить изучать язык нельзя по определению т.к. все языки программирования так или иначе меняются, да и просто, банально знать всего невозможно физически
****
2 TS

Судя по тому как вы формулируете свои мысли "что дальше надо изучать frameworks" - PHP вам учить надо а не (цитирую) "frameworks"

Comment: Я закончил изучать "учебный курс по PHP", который изучал.

Comment: учебный курс по PHP это, грубо - я закончил начальную школу =)

Comment: уточню) Разработка веб-приложений с помощью PHP и MySQL 4-е издание 
(Люк Веллинг, Лора Томсон) =)

Comment: Опять MVC %) @Shrek, [отпишитесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/61744/mvc-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83)?)

Comment: Практически все книги из разряда "разработка с помощью php ...." это books 4 noobs =)

Я вас уверяю - если бы вы были бы готовы для дальнейшего изучения вы бы не задавали этот вопрос, вы бы просто брали бы и учились.

По поводу mvc - потому что оно юзается во всех популярных php фреймворках + это модно + удобно для командной разработки (я не из тех кто арет что mvc - эта все, но факты остаются фактами)

Хотя я считаю что необходимо учить ООП и шаблоны проектирования в целом и, по возможности (на этапе обучения) не "циклиться" на чем либо

Comment: @AlexWindHope 

Я просто жду адекватного ответа о хороших сторонах MVC, чтобы принять ответ и закрыть вопрос. Я и в его удобстве для командной работы не уверен - тот же битрикс с нативными шаблонами и визивигом выглядит куда проще и для кодера (открыл файл - собрал массив) и для верстальщика (открыл файл - исправил тег). А копаться в этой "архитектуре"(Эшер, не иначе) смысла не вижу)

Comment: @Sh4dow - тут ты или сам поймешь, либо так и умрешь ненависником mvc

Я мог бы накатать довольно большой пример что, к чему и почему, но, зная твой настрой - смысла в этом не будет никакого.

Вообще не пойму - не нравиться MVC? Выкинь из головы и не используй.

Допустим в php вообще, легко можно писать все придерживаясь процедурного подхода, продумать структуру нормальную тоже можно (сам работал с такой - никаких проблем не было, работал в тиме).

MVC - это всего навсего "вариант", стандартом это стало потому-что использование оного навязывается поп. фреймворками (ну и модно, хуле :D)

Comment: Это не тот случай, когда настрой влияет на результат и тут не замешана религия) Я-то dev, а не сайтостроитель, мне по-барабану с чем работать так-то, просто интересная причина популярности притом, что она явно не удобнее многих других. И вот между прочим "стандартом это стало потому-что использование оного навязывается поп. фреймворками" - похоже на правду и даже понятнее стало.

Comment: @Sh4dow ты хочешь чтобы я в той теме отписался чтоли?

Отпишусь. ;)

ps в этой теме я все написал!

Comment: @Sh4dow отписался и ответ приняли :)  уважуха растет. я не успел сообразить как 100 упала за сегодня :)

Answer (score 3):

Из framework'ов на PHP наиболее активно использующиеся на данный момент это Zend и Symfony. Да и всё же соглашусь с предыдущими постами, по поводу практического опыта. Программисты-теоретики нужны только в университетах, чтобы было кому лекции читать.

Comment: daemon_master, а как на счет Yii?

Comment: Ребят кагбы вопрос был не "какой фреймворк выбрать", не?

Узнать какой фреймворк "лучше" поможет гугл (типа узнать т.к. все такие обсуждения сплошной тролинг и оффтоп)

Comment: Соглашусь, Zend и Symfony одни из наиболее встречающихся фрэймворков упоминающихся в требованиях на работу, в том числе в европейские и штатовские компании.
Учебники помогают разобраться со структурой языка, разбирание элементов фрэймворка помогает пониманию строения элементов приложения.

Comment: АЦЦТОЙ все комменты кроме @alexwindhope

-1 за ответ! невнимательность!

Answer (score 1):

Если выучили PHP, предлагаю такую задачу решить.

Вычислить выражение вида: 2+3(23-14(3/4+2*3))(2+3). Выражение может быть абсолютно любым. Вводиться через строковое поле. Обрабатывается php скриптом, а результат выводиться в браузер...

Ни в коем случае не использовать функцию eval()!!!!

Comment: `*`Шепотом`*` А пользоваться массивами и переводом в другие нотации можно?

Comment: Можно-можно)))) Единственное условие не использовать eval().

Comment: Кстати, это довольно интересная задача на понимание работы стека. Только зачем скрывать алгоритм? Изучайте: [обратная польская запись](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Answer (score 1):

Я понял, что что-то начал понимать в программировании, как только устроился на работу и проработал несколько месяцев, понял что многое понимал просто неправильно, а многое вообще не знал. Поэтому фраза: "Я уже закончил изучать PHP на базовом уровне" - это глупость, реализуйте какой-нибудь интересный Вам проект, выложите на githab, а потом снова сюда но уже с темой "Я уже закончил свой первый проект":)

А что изучать дальше - это зависит от того что Вам интересно, поставьте перед собой цель сделать что-то, обдумайте как будете делать на основе чего и... в путь!!!